# How to divide a string by another string using Split in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, split

I am trying to divide a string similar to this:

```cs
"<span>1</span> - Selection"
```

And get the value that is enclosed between the `<span>`.

In `JavaScript` I do this:

```js
var example= "<span>1</span> - selection";

var separation= example.replace("</span>","<span>").split("<span>");
console.log("Split: ",separation);
//The result is ["","1"," - Selección"]
console.log("Value that I want: ",separation[1]); //I get the value that I need
```

And that's it that I need to do but in Visual .NET, but it doesn't work for me.

I try:

```vb
Dim WordString As String = "<span>1</span> - Selection"
Dim idSelection As String() = WordString.Replace("</span>","<span>").Split("<span>")
```

or sending all the `</span>` replaced in the string to just do:

```vb
Dim WordString As String = "<span>1<span> - Selection"
Dim idSelection As String() = WordString.Split("<span>")
```

But in the position (1) I always get `"span>1"`, and I can't do the split like in `JS`

**How can I do it correctly?**

---

To simulate the code `VB.Net` use https://dotnetfiddle.net/

The code:

```vb
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim WordString As String = "<span>1</span> - Selection"
        Dim idSelection As String() = WordString.Replace("</span>","<span>").Split("<span>")
        Console.WriteLine(idSelection(1))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser would be best, another option is `regex` try this: `<span>(.|\n)*?<\/span>`. Again, there's more than a few ways to actually accomplish this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The first example works as in JS

Comment: @Steve use https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and paste the code, only add `Console.WriteLine(idSelection(1))` in the End

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I know that it's html, but the question isn't only for HTML, is for a String that y want divide by other string, do you know?

Comment: @FabianMontoya Yes, I do know how. I left a comment above about it, did you read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) to split using a string. So you can use the following solution:

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim WordString As String = "<span>1</span> - Selection"
        Dim idSelection As String() = WordString.Replace("</span>","<span>").Split({"<span>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Console.WriteLine(idSelection(0))
    End Sub
End Module
```

[**demo on dotnetfiddle.net**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wek8zQ)

You can also use a solution using a regular expression with a positiv lookahead and lookbehind:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim rgx As New Regex("(?<=<span>)(.+)(?=</span>)")
        Dim WordString As String = "<span>1</span> - Selection"

        If rgx.IsMatch(WordString) Then
            Console.WriteLine(rgx.Matches(WordString)(0))
        End If  
    End Sub
End Module
```

[**demo on dotnetfiddle.net**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uES8mc)

Comment: It works for me, thanks